While testing the game I made in Unity on an Android phone, the game restarted when I tried to open it again while it was in the background
I made a game in Unity and while testing it on my android phone someone called me and when I opened the game again it didn't continue where it left off. So what I noticed is that when the game goes into the background and I want to open it again it starts from the beginning.

This is nothing special. It just means that the game was removed from RAM, wuch can happen if you leave the app unopened for a while or do other things on your phone (like calling someone)

I do not agree with the close votes. The question is clear and factually answerable.

I didn't solve the problem though. I managed to keep users' saves safe by using the save system when exiting the game. I used OnApplicationPause to save.
